# Where does Windows Vista & 7 connect to test network/internet connectivity?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, connection

I haven't a windows machine to run a sniffer on to figure this out myself, so I'm here.

When Vista or 7 connect, they then do *something* and report either no connectivity, local only, local network only or connected to internet.  (paraphrased)

Where do they connect?  Might it be a simple DNS request? or are they pinging Microsoft.com or such?

My friends won't give up their computers for a short bit while I test this... but that's ok, I do maintenance for them, so one'll be here in a few weeks... it *is* windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a DNS request followed by an HTTP get of a text file, both from a Microsoft controlled domain.

---

Edit:

Effectively

- nslookup dns.msftncsi.com
- get http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt

"Network Connectivity Status Indicator"

Comment: Any chance of obtaining those urls?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126135(WS.10).aspx